# Pandas replace and str.replace difference

Tags: pandas

```
df["amount"] = df["amount"].replace(["undisclosed", "unknown", "Undisclosed"], "0")
```

when i use this code the values get replaced with Nan everywhere in the column

```
df['amount'] = df['amount'].str.replace('undisclosed','0')
df['amount'] = df['amount'].str.replace('unknown','0')
df['amount'] = df['amount'].str.replace('Undisclosed','0')`
```

but this works correctly .Can someone explain please

I need to replace the values

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you read the following notices, it will be better to get an answer. : [mre]

Comment: `replace` performs a full-match (by default), `str.replace` performs a partial (substring) match.